# Debug Qt application on Android device

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk

I went into a trouble debugging any Qt app on Android device - when I run debug mode and stop on breakpoint and if I have a Variables View open, it shows me multiple "The program has stopped because it received SIGABRT from OS" dialogs. I can close them and continue debug, but if Qt tries to update variables values in Variables View, it repeats, so debugging and seeing variables is almost impossible.

Configuration:
Qt 5.7, NDK 12, SDK for API 23, Sysroot - copied from the target device, OS - Win/Mac/Ubuntu (use all of them, same behaviour everywhere)

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you have to debug on Android? Can't you just compile your app for desktop and debug the code on desktop?

I always develop and debug most of the code on desktop, because recompile-run cycle is a lot quicker than on Android. If there's some bug, which only occurs on Android, I just use qDebug(). But I know that it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Andrej, thank you, we've also debugged Desktop version where possible and used qDebug output for Android/remote debugging Java code from Android SDK, etc., but, unfortunately, this is no longer an option due to hard-to-catch bugs in Android-specific native code.

Comment: Which version of QtCreator? Old versions were unable to correctly debug Android.